Why does the counter in the Votes/Revisions tab reflect activity immediately but not the public counters in your Activity page?
I noticed that if you go to your Votes tab in your profile, vote on a post, and then check back, the X Votes counter at the top of the list of posts you voted on will immediately update to reflect the change.
The same with Revisions. If you edit a post, the counter on top of the list of revisions you made that says X Revisions will immediately reflect the change.
However, if you view your public Votes cast table, vote on a post, and then check back, the change will not be reflected immediately. There is some delay for this feature to update. Similarly, if you view your public Impact table, edit a post, and then check back, there is a noticeable delay (1-2 minutes) before which, refreshing the page will show the updated numbers. The delay is less if you did not visit your profile recently before performing the action and checking back.
Is there some technical reason that prevents the public statistics from updating real-time, and why would this reason not apply to the Votes/Revisions counters? Would making the public statistics reflect changes immediately/real-time, like the counter in the Votes/Revisions, be technically feasible?
